# constexpr std::vector and constexpr std::string in C++20

Tags: c++, stdvector, constexpr, c++20, stdstring

In new c++20 std::vector and std::string have constexpr constructors (and other methods). I learned https://www.heise.de/developer/artikel/constexpr-std-vector-und-constexpr-std-string-in-C-20-4906108.html article that has examples of using constexpr versions of vector and string. But when i tried to test this code on https://godbolt.org with different compilers(last versions) - they totally all failed.

for example this code (with -std=c++20 key)

```
int main()
{
    constexpr std::vector myVec {15, -5, 0, 5, 10}; 
}
```

Is this feature not support yet? ...Or ..how to use this ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support
They aren't supported yet by big 3.

Answer (score 1):

To bring [@Jovibor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65122719/constexpr-stdvector-and-constexpr-stdstring-in-c20#comment115132819_65122719) to life - as stated in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), no compiler currently supports `constexpr std::vector` or `constexpr std::string`. You just have to wait a bit.